# Mongoid on RoR3: 1) how to return specific field on query? 2) what inverse_of is needed for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Well, the title is self-explicative. But, let me elaborate a little better.
First of all, I am using **Mongoid**, a Gem for using MongoDB with rails applications.

#1) I have a large collection, which has information about a map. A map embeds a lot of tiles, and each tile references a terrain collection, a user collection, and has some other information. Therefore, if I obtain all tiles from a map, I will have a really large structure. However, I would like to cache a structure that comprises a matrix with only the terrain information. In order to do that, I select all tiles (and hence, all their unneeded information) and use only the terrain field. How can I select ONLY the terrain field on Mongoid? I tried operating with select on several ways, but I did not manage to do it.. (by the way, just for the sake of exemplification, I access the tiles array with the line "Map.first.tiles").

#2) Well.. I am already here, so, why not ask this. Should I really use the inverse_of fields on my Models? I did not use it anywhere, and everything seems to be working perfectly. I do not see why it is needed, as it is pretty much straight forward to determine where to put them, and what they are the inverse of.

Thanks in advance.
Fernando.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In general, to only select 1 or more attributes in a mongoid query:

```
Map.only(:name).all
```

I wouldn't bother with inverse_only except when Mongoid needs help figuring out the classes. In general, not needed.

If you need to only return certain attributed on an embedded document, you'll want to use the full-path:

```
Map.first.tiles
 => [#<Tile _id: 4e1e486042f5bc06e7000002, name: "Earth", distance: 34>]

Map.only("tiles.name").first.tiles
 => [#<Tile _id: 4e1e488742f5bc06e7000003, name: "Earth", distance: nil>]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Regarding #1, I used "Map.only("tiles.row").first.tiles" and it returned several "#<Tile _id: , _type: nil, row: 99, col: nil, terrain_id: nil>" like files. Do you think there is any gain in performance when I select just the fields I will need? Or, by returning every other field as nil, the gain in performance will not matter? Thanks again! :)

Comment: There is quite a big performance gain in mongodb in returning only the fields you want (using the .only() scope).

Comment: Why isn't the `only` method showing in my MongoId? I am using version 3.0

Comment: I'm here because I remember using `only` some time ago when mogoid was not part of the mongodb project, and now I'm browsing the documentation and I couldn't find a single mention to it. Any idea why? has it been removed? deprecated? is there something (new) else that performas as the `only` Criteria? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `pluck`

> Criteria#pluck
>
> `Band.all.pluck(:name)`
>
> Get all the values for the provided field. Returns nil for unset
> fields and for non-existent fields.

source: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-queries/